# How to get the value of cookies once set

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to set and read a cookie value in asp.net core but the value is always null.

```
public async Task OnGet()
{
    //Session Variable
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserName", "User");

   // HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

    //Create new cookie          
    CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions();
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("user_id", "1", cookieOptions);


    //bool cookieValueFromReq = Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("user_Id", out string strval);

    cookieValue1 = Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("user_id", out string strval) ? strval : null;
```

I'm using cookie options to create a new cookie, which works. But I'm trying to figure out how to get the value of the cookie so I can read it.

Is there a way to read the cookie value in .net core? I've tried several ways that are commented out above. The last one was cookieValue1 which was null as well. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If you set a cookie to the `Response` property, you have to wait until the next round-trip until you can access it in the `Request` property.

Comment: It looks like you're attempting to store a user's ID in their cookie. This isn't a good idea. You should never put anything in a cookie that you don't want the user to see, and be able to change. A user can easily manipulate their cookies, and if the user ID is read from the cookie, then that gives user's an easy way to impersonate other users.

Comment: This is mainly just example of trying to get a cookie to work. I can get the cookies created. But I can't retrieve the value of the cookie once created. Are there other ways to save the Cookie value if not in Response property?

Comment: I'm afraid not.Maybe you can use Session to replace cookie.